# Trying to scrape the Yahoo finance "World Indices" List

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the "World Indices" list from Yahoo finance(https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/) into a dataframe using the code below. However, when I receive the following:

ValueError: No tables found

```
import pandas as pd
major_indices = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/")
df = pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_id("history_table").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
df.head()

Output:
ValueError: No tables found
```

I tried inspecting the page and realized that the table is surrounded by

```
<tbody data-reactid="36"> ... </tbody>.
```

I tried to search how to carry out the scraping but have not had any luck.

Is pandas datareader the way to go? Is there a more powerful web scraper I should use such as selenium or beautiful soup?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into BeautifulSoup for web scraping with Python. If you use an IDE like PyCharm it should be not too difficult to browe the BeautifulSoup object to find the contents of the webpage.

Here is a starter for your example.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website_html = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html)
table = soup.find("tbody", {"data-reactid": "36"})
table_text = [[cell.text for cell in row.contents] for row in table.contents]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from my side

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url='https://finance.yahoo.com/world-indices/';
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/681.3.9'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
df = pd.read_html(response.content)
print(df)
```

Pandas can extract the table from HTML pages.
Thus can be used to get the data of all the Index of the world.